# Get often occuring string patterns from column in R or Python

Tags: python, regex, r

I have a column of string names, and I would like to find often occuring patterns (words).
Is there a way to return, say, strings with a higher (or equal) length than X, and occur more often than Y times in the the whole column?

```
column <- c("bla1okay", "okay1243bla", "blaokay", "bla12okay", "okaybla")
getOftenOccuringPatterns <- function(.....) 
getOftenOccuringPatterns(column, atleaststringsize=3, atleasttimes=4)
>     what   times 
[1]   bla    5
[2]   okay   5
```

Referring to the comment by [Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20670/tim-pietzcker):

I would like the nested ones to be removed, so if there is "aaaaaaa" and "aaaa" and both would occur in the output, only "aaaaaaa" and the times that one occurs counts.

If `atleaststringsize=3` and `atleaststringsize=4`, both the output will be the same. Lets say `atleasttimes=10`, and "aaaaaaaa" occurs 15 times and "aaaaaa" occurs 15 times, then:

```
getOftenOccurringPatterns(column, atleaststringsize=3, atleasttimes=10)
>    what      times
[1]  aaaaaaaa    15
```

and

```
getOftenOccurringPatterns(column, atleaststringsize=4, atleasttimes=10) 
>    what      times
[1]  aaaaaaaa    15
```

The longest one stays, and it's the same thing for both atleast=3, and atleast=4.

Comment: Sounds like a fun problem. But regex is not going to be the way to solve it.

Comment: How should overlapping matches be handled? E. g., what's the desired result for `"abcdef", "abcd", "bcde", "cdef"`?

Comment: @TimPietzcker Only the longest should be kept.

Comment: Which is in this case? Also, imagine another string in your column: `"blaoka"`. What's the result now?

Comment: bla and okay do not overlap right? I'd say okayyy should remove okay, and blaaa should remove bla. "blaoka" should just give "blaoka", if it  is in the column often.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "remove". Please show the desired output for these cases.

Comment: Another question to help you understand what I'm trying to get at: What is the desired output for the column `"aaaaaaaa", "aaaaaaa", "aaaaaa", "aaaaa", "aaaa", "aaa"` and why?

Comment: @TimPietzcker when they all occur, only "aaaaaaaaa" will stay, with the amount of times it occurs in the text. When atleaststring = 5, then "aaaaaaa" will be in output, and "aaaaaaa" and "aaaaaaa" will not be there. Only the longest one, as long as it occurs at least y times.

Comment: Uh, those are all the same length...Please answer my question for the given set of data in my previous comment, for `atleaststring=3` and `atleasttimes=4`. What *exactly* should the output be?

Comment: @TimPietzcker I hope this clarifies in the updated question.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Please answer the question I asked. What is this "same" output? Same as what? Why is that so difficult?

Comment: @TimPietzcker I thought it was pretty clear, but I hope now it is.

Comment: Sorry, no. I'm not trying to appear stupid, but you keep not answering my question. Unless you do that, I can't help you. The question, again, is: What *exactly* is the output for the following function call: `getOftenOccuringPatterns(c("aaaaaaaa", "aaaaaaa", "aaaaaa", "aaaaa", "aaaa", "aaa"), atleaststringsize=3, atleasttimes=4)`?

Comment: @TimPietzcker Ah my bad, my apologies. Now I do understand. There are 6 of them, at least 4 times, so the common factor which is the highest is "aaaaa". It occurs at least 4 times, while being larger than "aaaa" and "aaa" (which both also occur 4 times). Though they are nested within "aaaaa", so output only: what = "aaaaa", times=4

Comment: Ok, thanks. So you don't want overlapping matches, otherwise `times` would have been `10`. Now what if the first string had been `"aaaaaaaaaa"` - would `times` have  been `5` then since `aaaaa` has two non-overlapping matches in `aaaaaaaaaa`?

Comment: @TimPietzcker I would prefer it to be counted only once within each cell, so times should be 4. I realize now that this becomes quite complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've written a solution in Python. Sorry, I can't give you a working R program, but you should be able to implement one from this. As you can see, this is quite a brute force solution, but I don't really see a way around building all possible substrings from all the strings in your input.

I've broken down the problem into simple, self-contained steps. These should be straightforward to translate into R. I'm sure that there are comparable data structures in R for lists, sets and counters.

```
from collections import Counter
strings = ["bla1okay", "okay1243bla", "blaokay", "bla12okay", "okaybla"]

def substrings(s, minlength=3):
    """Finds all possible unique substrings of s, given a minimum length.

    >>> substrings("12345")
    {'1234', '234', '345', '12345', '123', '2345'}
    >>> substrings("123123")
    {'2312', '123123', '12312', '123', '23123', '1231', '231', '3123', '312'}
    >>> substrings("aaaaa")
    {'aaaaa', 'aaaa', 'aaa'}
    """
    maxsize = current = len(s)
    result = []
    while current >= minlength:
        result.extend([s[start:start+current] 
                       for start in range(maxsize-current+1)])
                                  # range(5) is [0,1,2,3,4]
        current -= 1
    return set(result) # set() removes duplicates

def all_substrings(strings, minlength=3):
    """Returns the union of all the sets of substrings of a list of strings.

    >>> all_substrings(["abcd", "1234"])
    {'123', 'abc', 'abcd', '1234', 'bcd', '234'}
    >>> all_substrings(["abcd", "bcde"])
    {'abc', 'bcd', 'cde', 'abcd', 'bcde'}
    """
    result = set()
    for s in strings:
        result |= substrings(s, minlength)
        # "|=" is the set union operator
    return result

def count(strings, minlength=3):
    """Counts the occurrence of each substring within the provided list of strings,
    given a minimum length for each substring.

    >>> count(["abcd", "bcde"])
    Counter({'bcd': 2, 'bcde': 1, 'abc': 1, 'abcd': 1, 'cde': 1})
    """
    substrings = all_substrings(strings, minlength)
    counts = Counter()
    for substring in substrings:       # Check each substring
         for string in strings:        # against each of the original strings
             if substring in string:   # to see whether it is contained there
                 counts[substring] += 1
    return counts

def prune(counts, mincount=4):
    """Returns only the longest substrings whose count is >= mincount.
    First, all the substrings with a count < mincount are eliminated.
    Then, only those that aren't substrings of a longer string are kept.
    >>> prune(Counter({'bla': 5, 'kay': 5, 'oka': 5, 'okay': 5, 'la1': 2, 'bla1': 2}))
    [('okay', 5), ('bla', 5)]
    """
    # Throw out all counts < mincount. Sort result by length of the substrings.
    candidates = sorted(((s,c) for s,c in counts.items() if c >= mincount), 
                        key=lambda l: len(l[0]), reverse=True) # descending sort
    result = []
    seenstrings = set()      # Set of strings already in our result
    # (we could also look directly in the result, but set lookup is faster)
    for item in candidates:
        s = item[0]          # item[0] contains the substring
        # Make sure that s is not already in our result list
        if not any(s in seen for seen in seenstrings): 
            result.append(item)
            seenstrings.add(s)
    return result

counts = count(strings)
print(prune(counts))
```

Output:

```
[('okay', 5), ('bla', 5)]
```

Comment: It's okay actually, I use Python as well. I got it working, and while this is probably the same relative speed in R, Python is simply quicker, and fine for my goal for now. I'll change the question as to allow this question to be the answer, since you found a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Its in no way tested and wont win any speed races:

```
getOftenOccuringPatterns <- function(column, atleaststringsize, atleasttimes, uniqueInColumns = FALSE){

  res <- 
  lapply(column,function(x){
    lapply(atleaststringsize:nchar(x),function(y){
      if(uniqueInColumns){
        unique(substring(x, 1:(nchar(x)-y+1), y:nchar(x)))
      }else{
        substring(x, 1:(nchar(x)-y+1), y:nchar(x))
      }
    })
  })

  orderedRes <- unlist(res)[order(unlist(res))]
  encodedRes <- rle(orderedRes)

  partRes <- with(encodedRes, {check = (lengths >= atleasttimes);
                               list(what = values[check], times = lengths[check])})
  testRes <- sapply(partRes$what, function(x){length(grep(x, partRes$what)) > 1})

  lapply(partRes, '[', !testRes)

}


column <- c("bla1okay", "okay1243bla", "blaokay", "bla12okay", "okaybla")
getOftenOccuringPatterns(column, atleaststringsize=3, atleasttimes=4)
$what

 "bla" "okay" 

$times

5 5 


getOftenOccuringPatterns(c("aaaaaaaa", "aaaaaaa", "aaaaaa", "aaaaa", "aaaa", "aaa"), atleaststringsize=3, atleasttimes=4)
$what
[1] "aaaaaa"

$times
[1] 6


getOftenOccuringPatterns(c("aaaaaaaa", "aaaaaaa", "aaaaaa", "aaaaa", "aaaa", "aaa"), atleaststringsize=3, atleasttimes=4, uniqueInColumn = TRUE)
$what
[1] "aaaaa"

$times
[1] 4
```

Comment: Cool! Looks impressive, even though I don't understand it. I should start reading some R books. Very concise, but still readable syntax. Nice.

Comment: Thanks @TimPietzcker I just copied your ideas ;)

Comment: It's really slow. For some reason it did work on a list of 1000 strings (took a minute or so), I have to run it on 16000. Biggest problem is that it errors;
Error in grep(x, partRes$what) (from #19) : 
  invalid regular expression ' *** ', reason 'Invalid use of repetition operators'

Comment: Without your data set it is hard to comment. There is no error correcting. Are there strings in your `column` with number of characters less then `atleaststringsize`.

Comment: It is likely to be slow. What you are asking to do is not going to be fast for a large number of columns.

Comment: You can try adding `fixed = TRUE` to the grep argument.

Answer (score 2):

This creates a vector of all occurrences of all substrings; it does so naively, iterating over the maximum length of the input string max(nchar(x)) and looking for all subsequences of length 1, 2, ... max(nchar(x)), so scales in polynomial time -- it won't be efficient for super-large problems.

This revision incorporates the following changes:

1. `.accumulate` in inner and outer loops of the previous version implemented the dreaded "copy-and-append" pattern; now we accumulate results in a pre-allocated list `answer0` and then accumulate these after the inner loop.
2. `allSubstrings()` has arguments `min_occur`, `min_nchar` (and `max_nchar`) to restrict the search space. In particular, `min_occur` (the minimum number of times a substring must occur to be retained) helps to reduce the length of the character vector in which longer substrings are searched.
3. The function `.filter()` can be used to more aggressively remove strings that do not contain substrings of length i; this can be costly, so there's a heuristic and argument `useFilter` that can be set. The use of a filter makes the whole solution seem more like a hack than an algorithm -- the information about substrings has already been extracted, so we shouldn't have to go back and search for their occurrence again.

Here is the revised main function

```
allSubstrings <-
    function(x, min_occur=1L, min_nchar=1L, max_nchar=max(nchar(x)),
             ..., useFilter=max(nchar(x)) > 100L)
{
    len <- nchar(x)
    x <- x[len >= min_nchar]; len <- len[len >= min_nchar]
    answer <- vector("list", max_nchar - min_nchar + 1L)
    for (i in seq(min_nchar, max_nchar)) {
        ## suffix of length i, starting at character j
        x0 <- x; len0 <- len; n <- max(len0) - i + 1L
        answer0 <- vector("list", n)
        for (j in seq_len(n)) {
            end <- j + i - 1L
            f <- factor(substr(x0, j, end))
            answer0[[j]] <- setNames(tabulate(f), levels(f))
            x0 <- x0[len0 != end]; len0 <- len0[len0 != end]
        }
        answer0 <- unlist(answer0)        # accumulate across start positions
        answer0 <- vapply(split(answer0, names(answer0)), sum, integer(1))
        answer0 <- answer0[answer0 >= min_occur]
        if (length(answer0) == 0L)
            break
        answer[[i - min_nchar + 1L]] <- answer0

        idx <- len != i                   # no need to process some strings
        if (useFilter)
            idx[idx] <- .filter(x[idx], names(answer0))
        x <- x[idx]; len <- len[idx]
        if (length(x) == 0L)
            break
    }
    unlist(answer[seq_len(i)])
}
```

and the `.filter` function

```
.filter <-
    function(s, q)
{
    ## which 's' contain at least one 'q'
    answer <- rep(FALSE, length(s))
    idx <- !answer      # use this to minimize the number of greps
    for (elt in q) {
        answer[idx] <- answer[idx] | grepl(elt, s[idx], fixed=TRUE)
        idx[idx] <- !answer[idx]
    }
    answer
}
```

As before result is a named vector, where the names are the strings and the values are the counts of their occurrence.

```
> column <- c("bla1okay", "okay1243bla", "blaokay", "bla12okay", "okaybla")
> xx <- allSubstrings(column)
> head(sort(xx, decreasing=TRUE))
 a  b  o  k  l  y 
10  5  5  5  5  5 
> xtabs(~nchar(names(xx)) + xx)
                xx
nchar(names(xx))  1  2  3  5 10
              1   2  1  1  5  1
              2   8  2  0  5  0
              3  15  1  0  3  0
              4  20  1  0  1  0
              5  22  0  0  0  0
....
```

Queries like in the original question are then easy to perform, e.g., all substrings of >= 3 characters occurring more than 4 times:

```
> (ok <- xx[nchar(names(xx)) >= 3 & xx > 4])
 bla  oka  kay okay 
   5    5    5    5
```

The code doesn't fully answer the question, e.g., nested substrings are present, but might replace the nested `lapply` portion of @user1609452's answer. Post-processing this result to eliminate nested subsequences is a little inelegant, but since the result being post-processed is not large will likely be fast enough, e.g., to eliminate nested substrings

```
> fun <- function(p, q) length(grep(p, q, fixed=TRUE))
> ok[ sapply(names(ok), fun, names(ok)) == 1L ]   
 bla okay 
   5    5
```

Here we use the 99k word dictionary on my laptop for input, with some basic timings for the revised algorithm

```
> timer <- function(n, x, ...)
    system.time(allSubstrings(head(x, n), ...))[[3]]
> n <- c(100, 1000, 10000, 20000)
> data.frame(n=n, elapsed=sapply(n, timer, words))
      n elapsed
1   100   0.050
2  1000   0.074
3 10000   0.490
4 20000   1.031
```

This is about 10x faster than the original algorithm, due in this case entirely to revision 1 (using pre-allocate and fill, followed by accumulation).

Here's a corpus of longer sentences

```
shakes <- readLines("http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/100/pg100.txt")
shakes <- paste(shakes[nchar(shakes) != 0], collapse=" ")
shakes <- gsub(" +", " ", shakes)
shakes <- strsplit(shakes, "\\. +",)[[1]]
```

and some timings. This benefits alot from specifying a `min_occur` argument, and from use of the filter.

```
> n <- c(100, 1000, 2000, 5000)
> data.frame(n=n, elapsed=sapply(n, timer, shakes, min_occur=10))
     n elapsed
1  100   1.725
2 1000   7.724
3 2000  12.415
4 5000  60.914
```

The need to use a filter and the poor performance on longer strings leads one to want to arrive at a better algorithm, like [suffix array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array); the "Rlibstree" package might also be useful, although I'm unsure of where to get a current version or whether the exposed part of the interface is sufficient to answer the original question.

Comment: I do not really understand what the numbers are that you are outputting, nor how to use the .accumulate? Maybe could you explain that part?

Comment: @Dualinity `.accumulate` is used internally; I included it for completeness. I have added an example of how the data returned by `allSubstrings()` can be queried for what you're interested in, i.e., all substrings with three or more characters occurring more than 4 times. Hopefully it's a good strategy to arrive at a data structure (the named vector) that you can then use with more-or-less straight-forward R commands to get your specific results quickly and easily.

Comment: This is great. I always appreciate the time and effort @MartinMorgan puts in to his answers.

Comment: I only get numbers instead of the names of the columns 
(while running the latest code)

Comment: It is quite slow on sentences, 100 sentences: system.time() > [1]  45.168   0.344  45.691

Comment: @Dualinity I've updated the implementation; it's probably still too slow as the number of strings gets large.